# Recreate a component?

Tags: svelte

Is there a way to recreate a component in Svelte?

The context is that I have a component which has already been created. Once it completes its process, I would like for it to be destroyed and then created again. This would restore its properties to their default state, and ensure that the same is done for its nested components.

I imagine that this is technically possible with the existing component methods, but I was wondering if there's a straightforward way to go about it.

As an aside, I'm aware that recreating a component might be inefficient in some contexts. It might be preferable to achieve the desired recreation effect by manually resetting the state of the component and its nested components. For instance, a recursive function could somehow traverse the component and its nested components, and invoke the default data function of each. However, this is not so straightforward, and there are problematic aspects (i.e. computed properties and creation lifecycle hooks).

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**, using a [{#key}](https://svelte.dev/docs#key) block:

```html
<script>
import YourComponent from "./YourComponent.svelte"

let unique = {}

function restart() {
  unique = {} // every {} is unique, {} === {} evaluates to false
}
</script>

{#key unique}
  <YourComponent />
{/key}

<button on:click={restart}>Restart</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/286559382580492c8288e53a3597d7e1?version=3.28.0)

`{#key}` was introduced in Svelte v3.28, before that you needed to use a keyed `{#each}` block [with only one item](https://svelte.dev/repl/65c80083b515477784d8128c3655edac?version=3.24.1)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, to recreate a component in its factory-fresh state you would need to call `new Thing(...)` again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think there might be any merit to having a component method like `recreate` for this purpose? Perhaps this question might be suited to a discussion in the GitHub repository.

Comment: GitHub would be the place to have that discussion, yeah — my instinct is that it's probably not that useful, since all the `recreate` logic probably wouldn't be any cheaper than reinstantiation, but I could be misunderstanding or missing something!