# Restart or re-init component in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Is there an easy way to force a restart of Svelte components in place?

Restart use cases:

- Clear file list of HTML files input (you cannot reset the path / value)
- Nav bar dropdown collapse after item selection when using CSS hover

Maybe there are other solutions besides the restart, but lets use a component restart here.

Below the restart code which works fine for the upload use case:

**SomeApp.svelte**

```html
<script>
      ...
      import Upload from "./upload/Upload.svelte";

      export let uid;  // firebase uid from auth

      // restart the Upload component after the upload 
      // to clear the filename of the <input type="file" ..../>  
      // restart by making use of a dynamic (falsy) component
      let upload_component = Upload;
      let restart = false;

      $: if (restart) {
         // use a falsy to stop / destroy this component 
         upload_component = null;
         // use a timer to queue a restart after the component has stopped
         setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('Upload component restarts')
           upload_component = Upload
         }, 0);
         console.log('Upload component restart queued');
         restart = false;  
      };

      ...
</script>


<!-- dynamic upload to restart the component when finished-->
<svelte:component uid={uid} this={upload_component} bind:finished={restart}/>
```

**Upload.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import { onDestroy } from 'svelte';
    import { uploadCsv } from './upload.js'

    export let uid = null;
    export let finished;

    function uploadCsvCallback(result) {
      console.log(result);
      finished = true;
    };

    onDestroy(() => {
      console.log('Upload component destroyed');
    });
</script>

<style>
     .float-right {
          float: right;
      }
</style>

<!-- Select a CSV file to batch import a Firestore collection -->
<input
    type="file" name="files" class="float-right" accept=".csv" 
    on:change={uploadCsv(uid, uploadCsvCallback)}
/>
```

**Update:**
A component gets destroyed if the components is not rendered. So you can stop and restart a component when you toggle an if block arround a component.

Example:
 1. toggle run from true to false to destroy the Upload component
 2. and toggle run from false to true to restart the Upload component

```
{#if run}
  <Upload .....>
{/if}
```

And you can use a timer to toggle the restart.

```
run = true:
function restartComponent() {
  restart = false;  // stop / destroy
  setTimeout(() => run = true, 0); // and queue a restart
}
```

Comment: if nothing has changed from 02'2018 then no, we cannot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911519/recreate-a-component

Comment: OK. I'am nog familiar with Svelte before 3. And 3 was a majon overhaul. I assume restart is possible, but not ...

Comment: It can akso be done without a dynamic component. When a component is not rendered while "active" it is destroyed. This means we can put the above <input files ...> in an if block. If we toggle the if block the component restarts.

Comment: cool idea! do you mind composing official answer with small demo?

Comment: I have updated the question with the if block restart.

Comment: please move that into explicit answer! I worry about someone who may miss opening this question from search just because it does not have any answer(so they will not know you have provided solution right in the question part)

Comment: btw you may have `{#if toggler}{else}{/if}` with exact code for `if` and `else` parts where `toggler` boolean variable is just inverted each time you want to reset state.

Comment: This will not work. You have to queue the "true", AFTER THE RENDER of the "false". For this reason I used a timer.

Comment: I've created small sandbox, and `{#if}{:else}` works there. https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-wind-s1jny

Comment: Very nice to solve the filname problem this way in Svelte (without a restart). But I do not think you can restart a Svelte component this way (without a timer).

Comment: Great question!!!

Answer (score 28):

**Yes**, using a [{#key}](https://svelte.dev/docs#key) block:

```html
<script>
import YourComponent from "./YourComponent.svelte"

let unique = {}

function restart() {
  unique = {} // every {} is unique, {} === {} evaluates to false
}
</script>

{#key unique}
  <YourComponent />
{/key}

<button on:click={restart}>Restart</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/286559382580492c8288e53a3597d7e1?version=3.28.0)

`{#key}` was introduced in Svelte v3.28, before that you needed to use a keyed `{#each}` block [with only one item](https://svelte.dev/repl/65c80083b515477784d8128c3655edac?version=3.24.1)

Comment: Great answer!!!