# How to return new component when a signal updates in Solid-JS?

Tags: solid-js

In Solid, components are not re-rendered when their dependencies change but I would like to return a fresh value whenever a signal updates.

This is similar to [this Svelte question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911519/recreate-a-component).

**Example A**

In the following example, I would like to return a different `input` element whenever `foo` changes.

```js
export default () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = createSignal();

  return <input .../>;
};
```

**Example B**

Another example is where a component `Foo` intentionally takes in certain props that are not reactive, and we would like to reconstruct `Foo` if we need to pass in a new value for that prop.

Motivation: This might occur if a component doesn't want arbitrary CRUD-based changes to props, but instead wants more structured state transitions, and anything outside these transitions would require a complete reconstruction of the component instance.

In the below example, `day` is not reactive, but `time` is.

```js
const Foo = (day, time) => {
  // day: "mon", "tue", etc.
  // time: "day-time", "night-time"

  const weather = fetch_weather(day);
  
  return <>
    <Show when={time() === "day-time"}>
      {weather.dayTimeResults}
    </Show>
    <Show when={time() === "night-time"}>
      {weather.nightTimeResults}
    </Show>
  </>
};

export const Weather = () => {
  const [day, setDay] = createSignal();
  const [time, setTime] = createSignal();

  // This does not work
  return <Foo day={day()} time={time}/>;
};
```

The above example is illustrating the idea that `Foo` acts as a sort of boundary where we want to introduce some structure to the state. Obviously one could just make `time` reactive instead, but this defeats the purpose of trying to incorporate this architectural structure into the design (across a component boundary). Hopefully I'm explaining myself adequately.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to return different elements based on a condition is using a memo. Since the returned elements are wrapped in a memo, they will be tracked by their consumers too. If you check the  built-in components you will see that is how they return a different component based on a condition.

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, createMemo, JSX } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal(1);
  const increment = () => setCount(count() + 1);

  const comp = createMemo(() => {
    if (count() % 2 === 0) {
      return <button type="button" onClick={increment}>Inc</button>
    }

    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
        Count: {count()} {Date.now()}
      </button>
    );
  }) as unknown as JSX.Element

  return comp;
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

Live Demo: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/bdb6e250-899f-4d82-8317-8658fd5eabb2

Please note that online playground has some issues with exported JSX and JSXElement:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'solid-js'
does not provide an export named 'JSX'
```

That is why I changed component type from JSX.Element to JSX.Element for the live demo. The code snippet should work without any issues in an actual development environment.

Condition is not necessary, you can return an element directly but the value will not be reactive unless you track a signal inside the function:

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, createMemo } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal(1);
  const increment = () => setCount(count() + 1);

  const comp = createMemo(() => {
    return <input value={count() + Date.now()} />
  }) as any;

  return (
     <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
        Count: {count()} {comp}
      </button>
  );
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

Live Demo: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/0cd05f3b-17dd-406d-8296-a2379c95224c

A new input element is returned whenever the signal's value changes.

This pattern works because Solid invokes a function if it place inside a JSX element: `<button>{fn}</button>`. In React, this outputs the stringified definition of `fn`.

Memo returns a new element whenever the signal's value changes. To return a different value, you need to re-run the memo. For that you need to track the signal inside memo. In other words, you need to access the signal inside the memo function or explicitly track a signal.

If you remove the signal, memo will be stack with its initial value. So, if you need to return a new element, i.e input, but do not need to use signal's value, then you have to explicitly track the value using `on` function: https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#on

Comment: Thanks, `createMemo` makes perfect sense, however I notice I still have to state a dependency twice, for example `createMemo(() => { dependency(); return <Foo dependency={depenedency()}/> })`, any idea why this is neccessary?

Comment: That is because you are returning a component from a component. Here memo itself is a component, so you should return elements directly. In other words, whatever you do inside Foo do it inside the memo function.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however, I believe I *am* returning the element directly, if you look at my comment, I am using `return <Foo .../>` not `return () => <Foo .../>`, yet for some reason I still have to state the dependency twice. Am I missing something?

Comment: `createMemo(() => { dependency(); return <Foo dependency={depenedency()}/> })` this is component returning a component that returns elements. You are not returning elements directly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a way to return the element directly so that `dependency()` is not included twice?

Comment: The first example in the answer does that.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you want to avoid this kind of thing (recreating components), and opt to update only what is needed. If you are sure you need to re-render, the simple solution is to use the keyed prop of `<Show>`:

```js
export default () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = createSignal();

  return (
    <Show when={foo()} keyed>
      {foo => <input .../>}
    </Show>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but is a little bit sloppy, requiring each key or non-reactive prop to be stated twice.

#### New Answer

**Solution for Example A**

```
export default () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = createSignal();

  return <>{createMemo(() => {
    foo(); // include key here
    return <input .../>;
  })}</>;
};
```

**Solution for Example B**

```
export const Weather = () => {
  const [day, setDay] = createSignal();
  const [time, setTime] = createSignal();

  return <>{createMemo(() => {
    day(); // include non-reactive props here (to trigger reconstruction)
    return <Foo day={day()} time={time}/>;
  })}</>
};
```

#### Original Answer

**Solution for Example A**

```
export default () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = createSignal();

  return <Dynamic component={(() => {
    foo(); // include key here
    return () => <input .../>;
  })()}/>;
};
```

**Solution for Example B**

```
export const Weather = () => {
  const [day, setDay] = createSignal();
  const [time, setTime] = createSignal();

  return <Dynamic component={(() => {
    day(); // include non-reactive props here (to trigger reconstruction)
    return () => <Foo day={day()} time={time}/>;
  })()}/>
};
```